# how Copy or delete Image or file in any place to the Folder in the application in UWP

Tags: uwp

I attempted to transfer an image or file from my computer to a local folder within a UWP application, but I was unsuccessful. Every time I tried, I received an error message stating that access to the file was denied. To resolve this issue, I conducted thorough research on Google and explored various UWP sources on the Microsoft website. I diligently applied the methods and techniques suggested in those resources, but unfortunately, I was still unable to accomplish the task successfully.

Comment: Please show code. Did you get the file from a Picker? From a FutureAccessList?

Comment: Hello, do you get the file by path? UWP has restrictions on this. By default, it is not allowed to obtain files by path. You can try [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks too much.
I found the solution and your answers are useful.

this is the solution

This is the upload Button Image

```
        private async void BtnAddImage_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var imagePicker = new FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop,
            FileTypeFilter = { ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif", ".tif" }
        };


        var imageFile = await imagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (imageFile == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _storageFile = imageFile;
        _path = imageFile.Path;

        var dataPackage = new DataPackage();

        dataPackage.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(imageFile));
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);




        var dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
        if (!dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap)) return;


        IRandomAccessStreamReference imageReceived = await dataPackageView.GetBitmapAsync();


        if (imageReceived == null) return;
        using (var imageStream = await imageReceived.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);
            ImgSupplier.Source = bitmapImage;

        }

        StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(imageFile);
    }
```

retrun the path

```
    private static string GetPath(string folderName)
    {

  var root = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\Assets\";

        var fullPath = Path.Combine(root, folderName);
        return fullPath;
    }
```

This is a save button

```
    private StorageFile _storageFile;   
    private async void BtnAddExpenditure_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var getPath = GetPath("Companies");

        var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(getPath);
        await _storageFile.CopyAsync(folder, Guid.NewGuid() + "." + _storageFile.FileType);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, UWP apps do not have access to the file system, there are a couple ways to gain access while still giving the user control over the action. The first one is through the file picker, you can save a token after the user picks a file so that you can access the file again in the future without asking the user.
Another option is to use the BroadFileAccess capability in order to access files without asking the user to choose it in the file picker. Before this option works, the user will need to grant file access to the app from the Windows 10 privacy settings.